# divergence in gradient descent algorithm for linear neural network model

Tags: matlab, neural-network, gradient-descent, least-squares

I'm trying to train a linear neural network(with out any activation functions) that  inputs are exactly same as targets. I have n*3 train/target data and weights matrix is 3*3 , but gradient descent doesn't converge to minimum.

I generated my data from a plane as below in matlab :

```
m=50
x=rand(m,1);
y=rand(m,1);
z=2.*x + 3.*y + 1;
X=[x,y,z];
```

after that my gradient descent :

```
w=0.001*rand(3,3); 

n=0.01;%learning rate
for i=1:100 
    
    Y=(X*w); %output
     
    error=(D-Y);
    
    w=w+n*error'*X;
    
    
end
```

what is the problem?? weights and errors has been exploded and they was large numbers!!!
can you help me to know what is my mistakes or totally my NN architecture has problem?
thanks

Comment: This code does not run because `D` is undefined....

Comment: In my problem , D is target matrix  and it is equal to X

Comment: Look at your equations. If you are trying to minimize `D-Y` and `Y=X*w` and `D=X`, the solution is trivial. `w=1` will make `Y=X` and therefore `D-Y` or `X-Y` or `X-X` zero.

Comment: actually my purpose is that to find w . it is trivial analytically, But i want to find w with gradient descent

Comment: For any non-trivial equatrion of `z`, the solution will always be `w=1` because of how you are posing the problem. The desired output can not be the same as the input, or otherwise the solution is always 1. I suspect you may want to have `D=z` and `X=[x,y]` because otherwise this makes no sense